# Google JavaScript API v3 - Street View Service - turn off building interiors

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

Often the geocoding in my application will return rooftop accuracy.

When I zoom into the location, and I switch on street view, I will end up inside a building, rather than on the street.  I want to always be out on the street.

I was looking for some kind of configuration setting here: [street view documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview), that will allow me to turn off building interiors but no luck.  Can someone confirm whether or not what I'm looking for is possible?

Thanks.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4831&can=1&q=ApiType%3AJavascript3%20streetview&sort=-stars%20-modified%20-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal%20Modified

Comment: The code sample can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/49364292/5140781

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property we're looking for is `google.maps.StreetViewSource.OUTDOOR`. Docs:

- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#StreetViewSource

PS: Thanks to geocodezip for the bug tracking URL reference.

Answer (score 1):

That ability doesn't currently exist, see [this enhancement request for the API](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4831&can=1&q=ApiType%3AJavascript3%20streetview&sort=-stars%20-modified%20-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal%20Modified) (star it if you are interested in having it added)