# Detect inside/outside panorama from StreetViewService

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

With StreetViewService.getPanoramaByLocation it is possible to find panorama by location. 
Is it any way to check what result panorama is inside view?

If you drag Pegman over map then map will show orange circles for inside panoramas. Any chance to find those orange circles in JS?

Comment: [related issue](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4831)

Comment: thank you, found [kind of answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796604/how-to-know-if-street-view-panorama-is-indoors-or-outdoors) in comments for the  mentioned issue