# Google Street View: How to get indoor panoramas as Google does

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I'm looking for a way to get exactly the same indoor panoramas for businesses Google is showing in [Google maps] (can't add any more links).

**What I did**:
google.maps.StreetViewService class requires either lng/lat or pano ID, so...

- convert business address to lng/lat using google.maps.Geocoder (issues occured, see below)
  e.g. `Richard-Wagner-Str. 7, 04109 Leipzig, Germany`
- convert business to lng/lat using google.maps.Place (issues occured, see below)
  e.g. `Park Hotel, Richard-Wagner-Str. 7, 04109 Leipzig, Germany`
- thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796604/how-to-know-if-street-view-panorama-is-indoors-or-outdoors/15019667#15019667) I found a way to get pano ID for a certain address

**Issues**:
None of this was working as I hoped for...

- get indoor panorama by converting business address to lng/lat:
  found resulting panorama to be wrong business at same address (got [restaurant](https://www.google.de/maps/place/Steaktrain/@51.3433977,12.3788728,3a,75y,52h,90t/data=!3m8!1e1!3m6!1su5IFILOjRj8AAAQYaRb04w!2e0!3e2!6s%2F%2Fgeo0.ggpht.com%2Fcbk%3Fcb_client%3Dmaps_sv.tactile%26output%3Dthumbnail%26thumb%3D2%26panoid%3Du5IFILOjRj8AAAQYaRb04w%26w%3D124%26h%3D75%26yaw%3D52%26pitch%3D0%26thumbfov%3D103%26ll%3D51.343398,12.378873!7i7000!8i3500!4m7!1m4!3m3!1s0x47a6f82241472917:0x4fe43e5a59cb8b2!2sRichard-Wagner-Stra%C3%9Fe+7,+04109+Leipzig!3b1!3m1!1s0x47a6f822411a56f1:0x510e609344adc2ba!6m1!1e1), wanted [hotel](https://www.google.de/maps/place/Park+Hotel/@51.3433467,12.3791139,3a,75y,305h,90t/data=!3m8!1e1!3m6!1sZqjE-wgztqMAAAQYan7iiA!2e0!3e2!6s%2F%2Fgeo0.ggpht.com%2Fcbk%3Fcb_client%3Dmaps_sv.tactile%26output%3Dthumbnail%26thumb%3D2%26panoid%3DZqjE-wgztqMAAAQYan7iiA%26w%3D124%26h%3D75%26yaw%3D305%26pitch%3D0%26thumbfov%3D103%26ll%3D51.343347,12.379114!7i7000!8i3500!4m12!1m9!2m8!1sHotels!3m6!1sHotels!2sSteaktrain,+Richard-Wagner-Stra%C3%9Fe+7,+04109+Leipzig!3s0x47a6f822411a56f1:0x510e609344adc2ba!4m2!1d12.3790222!2d51.3434598!3m1!1s0x47a6f82269c93ce7:0xb23890ca9c799db3!6m1!1e1)) --- and no, there was no resulting array with multiple entries
- get indoor panorama by using whole search term with places API:
  got slightly different lng/lat but was outside panorama instead of inside
- get indoor panorama by pano ID:
  working fine but still was outside panorama

**Questions**:

- It must be working. Somehow. Any idea how Google's doing the job? (check with [Google maps](http://google.de/maps/place/Park+Hotel/@51.3433467,12.3791139,16z/data=!4m12!1m9!2m8!1sHotels!3m6!1sHotels!2sSteaktrain,+Richard-Wagner-Stra%C3%9Fe+7,+04109+Leipzig!3s0x47a6f822411a56f1:0x510e609344adc2ba!4m2!1d12.3790222!2d51.3434598!3m1!1s0x47a6f82269c93ce7:0xb23890ca9c799db3), review box on the left: using address responds with same outside pano Google shows as well. But how to get corresponding inside pano?)
- How to make sure a pano is inside, not outside?
- Quite often, Google offers multiple indoor panos for a certain business. Any suggestions how this may work?
- documentation of http://developers.google.com/places/place-id#id-overview says, place-id

  > "... can be used with Google Maps Javascript API ..."

  Any idea why not working with street view panos?

Many thanks!

**Update**
Making my questions more precise:

- How do I get same indoor panoramas as Google does?
- How do I get more than just one panorama per business (as Google does)?
- Any chance to make street view work with Google Places place_id?

Comment: Your question is too broad. Google has implemented [this feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4831) a few weeks ago. Please read through this thread. It has been implemented in the [experimental version](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#StreetViewSource) (3.21) of the api.

Comment: If I look up [Park Hotel, Richard-Wagner-Str. 7, 04109 Leipzig, Germany with the places API](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=Park%20Hotel,%20Richard-Wagner-Str.%207,%2004109%20Leipzig,%20Germany&place=1), I get Lat/Lng (51.343364, 12.378962999999999), if I use that for a StreetView, I get [the interior of the hotel](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/pfp1rd2p/1/).

Comment: @MrUpsidown: already found but it only allows for parameter 'OUTSIDE', not 'INSIDE'. Btw: couldn't it running, get error msg saying sth like 'unknown parameter source: OUTSIDE'

Comment: @geocodezip: as described, you'll get panorama for a restaurant called "SteakTrain" not the desired hotel "Park Hoetl" (which is at the same address). Btw: your example says the same. See location tag left top

Comment: @00willson yes I know. That's why I told you to read through the thread. This way you understand what is available and what is not.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this tool to extract pano ID :)

[www.ekreativa.com/pano-id-extract/](http://www.ekreativa.com/pano-id-extract/)